# awk search pattern in file. replace line on match and print as it is on not match

Tags: shell, replace, sed, awk, match

I have a TAB separated file like this:

sample.rpt:

```
54 67 common/bin/my/home {{bla bla bla}} {bla bla} ReplaceMe

89 75 bad/rainy/day/out {{ some bla} } {some bla} DontreplaceMe
```

I wish to do a regexp match on the 3rd item, say `common/bin/my/home`
and if there is a match i want to replace the 6th item `Replace Me` by
my own text like `happy Home`

Additionally my regexp will be a shell variable, so I need a command
which accepts regexp as variable

The items may have spaces or backslashes and the file is Tab
separated.

To achieve this I used following awk one-liner:

Below I am checking if field 3 matches the pattern specified by drv,
then do whatever is in braces {}

```
awk -F "\t" -v drv=$mod_pat '$3 ~ drv \
  { OFS= "\t"; $6 = " happy_home"; print;}' sample.rpt
```

The problem now is I want to just print the line untouched if the
pattern is not matched. Is this possible in the same command ?

I tried:

```
awk -F "\t" -v drv=$mod_pat \
  'if ($3 ~ drv) { OFS= "\t"; $6 = " happy_home"; print;} else {print;}' sample.rpt
```

But its throwing parse error. Probably some problem with awk syntax.

Comment: [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for improved readability.

Answer (score 3):

`1` is a pattern with default action  `{print $0}`
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Very-Simple.html

```
awk -F\t -v OFS=\t -v drv="home" '$3~drv{$6=" happy_home"} 1' sample.rpt
```

Comment: Thanks a slight modification helped me:
awk -F "\t" -v drv=$mod_pat '$3 ~ drv \
  { OFS= "\t"; $6 = " happy_home";} 1' sample.rpt

Answer (score 1):

You need `{}` around the `awk` program if you're going to use an "`if`" statement.  E.g:

```sh
awk -F "\t" -v drv=$mod_pat '{ if ($3 ~ drv) { OFS= "\t"; $6 = " happy_home"; print;} else {print;} }' sample.rpt
```